# Error while creating sftp only user on ubuntu server

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp

I want to create a new user and restrict the user for only sftp access where also the user is restricted within a directory and cannot access root directory.

I did the following steps:

1) created a new group called `sftp-users`.

2) created a new user called `myUser` and set its password.

3) added `myUser` to `sftp-users` group.

4) `/var/www/example.com` is the project directly within which I want to restrict this users SFTP access. I used `usermod` command to set this directory as home directory of `myUser`.

5) Used: `usermod -s /sbin/nologin myUser` to restrict shell access

6) On  /`etc/ssh/sshd_config` file
I commented the following line

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

and added the following line instead of it

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Finally at the bottom of the file I added following rules

```
Match Group sftp-users
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Now when I try to login using:

```
ssh myUser@localhost
```

After entering the password and it gives me the following error

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 22: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Ownership details of the `/var` directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root   4096 Jan 15  2018 ./
drwxrwxr-x 23 root root   4096 Jul  4 06:08 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul 20 06:25 backups/
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root   4096 Jun 23 17:00 cache/
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Jan 12  2018 crash/
drwxr-xr-x 53 root root   4096 Jun 23 17:00 lib/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 12  2016 local/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Jan 12  2018 lock -> /run/lock/
drwxr-xr-x 11 root syslog 4096 Jul 20 06:25 log/
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail   4096 Jan 12  2018 mail/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jun 23 16:14 opt/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Jan 12  2018 run -> /run/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Nov 30  2017 snap/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Jan 15  2018 spool/
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root   4096 Jul 20 01:45 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jul  9 08:05 www/
```

Ownership details of the `/var/www` directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root        root      4096 Jul  9 08:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 root        root      4096 Jan 15  2018 ../
drwxr-sr-x  6 myUser      user2     4096 Jul 18 15:36 example.com/
```

Comment: `root` has to be the user which owns the chrooted dir.  For the chroot to be created, you need superuser, which is why you need to have `root` own that directory/folder.  Something about 'jailed chroot' or something.  Discovered that when making a chroot jail for one of my users on a specific server at work.

Comment: `drwxr-sr-x  6 root root 4096 Jul 18 15:36 example.com/` This is the details after changing ownership to root but still same error.

Comment: No, I said only change the owner *user* not the group... you can't apply the chroot without the group being set properly.  `sudo chown root:sftp-users /var/www/example.com`

Comment: @ThomasWard ok done `drwxr-sr-x 6 root sftp-users 4096 Jul 18 15:36 example.com/` But still the same error